# ConstraintLayout Notification Badge

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Regarding ConstraintLayout Notification Badge

I have used ConstraintLayout for notification as shown below.

here i used ImageButton and textview
  [image]

out put:

[image]

here i used Button and textview

[image]

output :

[image]

insted of imageview is used button then it look like this.
can any help me to solve this in constraintLayout.

ex : [image]

when i tryed with button it displaying like this .

one more new thing i got to know if you are using FrameLayout or RelativeLayout display badge is working fine for both Button , ImageView or ImageButtom.

But on long-press or click of Button Notification badge is going back , in Imageview and imagebutton it working fine.

Comment: Can you try adding android:elevation="0dp" for your button

Comment: i tried it's not working if elevation="10dp" shadow is displaying

Comment: I mean use 0dp elevation for button and not use any elavtion for badge

Comment: yes i tried it's not working

Comment: It's better to add actual code and not pictures of the code.

Comment: I already given the xml you can see button and Notification in second XML

Answer (score 3):

This happens, because Button has its own elevation.

Higher elevation, gets views to the front.

Try adding higher elevation to your Badge like below.

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

And, you don't want to scale your Image, you must use ImageView or ImageButton.

Comment: it not require if i am using ImaeView or ImageButton, but i need to use button.if i use elevation it showing shadow.

Comment: @RKiranKumar why do you need to Use a Button? And android:elevation="10dp" did solve your problem?

Comment: i wants to try it in button

Comment: @RKiranKumar If you have an image on your button, use ImageButton, there is no difference. That's why it is created for.

Answer (score 2):

Use this `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` in the Button xml

```
<Button
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Borderless buttons resemble basic buttons except that they have no borders or background but still change appearance during different states, such as when clicked.

Comment: If it working for you, you can accept the answer future reference.

Comment: Sorry this is not working if i apply style in background is disappear , it's not correct .

Comment: In your code, you are setting the image as the background.

Comment: if i use com.abc.xysmm.Button and ther no background it showing as transprant

Answer (score 0):

Final i got the solution for the above question

1 : for Button 
    android:elevation will not effect beacuse internal it has elevation.

```
instead of elevation use android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

2 : for other then button elevation will work